# PHP: Pagination with Html Values

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to display db records using pagination. I want to define html values in a html form and then pass these values to $post value in PHP. The first page populates correctly but when the button is pressed all values disappear.I hard coded in some values and it worked correctly.

This is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
   <h1>Please Enter Your Search Requirements</h1>
 </header>
<body>

<form method="post" action="teeeestt.php">
<h1>Renter Details</h1>
Location: <input type="text" name="renterLocation"><br>
<br>
Minimum Age: <input type="number" name="MinrenterAge" required ><br>
<br>
Maximum Age: <input type="number" name="MaxrenterAge" required ><br>
<br>
Gender: <select name="renterGender">
 <option value="Male">Male</option>
 <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select><br>
<br>
Interest: <input type="text" name="renterinterest"><br>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="rentersmoker" value="Yes">Smokers<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the PHP

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <?php
        $renterlocation = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'renterLocation');
        $renterminage = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'MinrenterAge');
        $rentermaxage = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'MaxrenterAge');
        $rentergender = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'renterGender');
        $renterinterest = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'renterinterest');
        $rentersmoker = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rentersmoker');
            include("config.php");

            $rowperpage = 1;
            $row = 0;

            // Previous Button
            if(isset($_POST['but_prev'])){
                $row = $_POST['row'];
                $row -= $rowperpage;
                if( $row < 0 ){
                    $row = 0;
                }
            }

            // Next Button
            if(isset($_POST['but_next'])){
                $row = $_POST['row'];
                $allcount = $_POST['allcount'];

                $val = $row + $rowperpage;
                if( $val < $allcount ){
                    $row = $val;
                }
            }
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="content">
        <table width="100%" id="emp_table" border="0">
            <tr class="tr_header">
                <th>S.no</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            // count total number of rows
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cntrows FROM renttable WHERE rentlocation = '$renterlocation' AND rentAge  BETWEEN '$renterminage' AND '$rentermaxage' AND rentGender = '$rentergender' AND (rentInterest     = '$renterinterest' OR '$renterinterest' LIKE '%') AND rentSmoker = '$rentersmoker'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            $fetchresult = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $allcount = $fetchresult['cntrows'];

            // selecting rows
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM renttable WHERE rentlocation = '$renterlocation' AND rentAge  BETWEEN '$renterminage' AND '$rentermaxage' AND rentGender = '$rentergender' AND (rentInterest     = '$renterinterest' OR '$renterinterest' LIKE '%') AND rentSmoker = '$rentersmoker'  ORDER BY rentId ASC limit $row,".$rowperpage;
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            $sno = $row + 1;
            while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $name = $fetch['rentName'];
                $salary = $fetch['rentAge'];
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td align='center'><?php echo $sno; ?></td>
                    <td align='center'><?php echo $name; ?></td>
                    <td align='center'><?php echo $salary; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
                $sno ++;
            }
            ?>
        </table>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <div id="div_pagination">
                <input type="hidden" name="row" value="<?php echo $row; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="allcount" value="<?php echo $allcount; ?>">
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="but_prev" value="Previous">
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="but_next" value="Next">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry! I dont understand what you want ?

Comment: I want to define values in the html. Enter these values into a sql query. Then have the results of the query display one at the time.

Comment: A few thoughts: 1) You need to use prepared statements; even with filter_input you should not use php to inject variables into a query string. 2) POST is for requests that change data; use GET for searches. 3) I chuckled when I read “This is the php: `<!DOCTYPE html>...`”. Do all your database access and business logic before you ever output anything.  4) I never saw any `limit` in your query; how do you expect to grab the right row?

Comment: oops, it appears that I didn’t scroll far enough to the right...